# Deep stubbing together with the doReturn method

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to use the Mockito *deep stubbing* feature with the `doReturn` method.

When I use the `when` method as in the deep stubbing example it works fine:

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");
```

But when I try then same thing with `doReturn` I get a `WrongTypeOfReturnValue`:

```
doReturn("deep").when(mock).getBar().getName();
```

I have also tried it these ways but then I get an `UnfinishedStubbingException`:

```
doReturn("deep").when(mock.getBar()).getName();
doReturn("deep").when(mock.getBar().getName());
```

How can I use the deep stubbing feature with the `doReturn` method?

*<sup>(I am aware that the use of deep stubbing is discouraged by some, including the Mockito developers. I'm not sure if I agree with their position on this. Let's keep that discussion out of this issue.)</sup>*

Comment: In your first attempt with `doReturn` you should not get `UnfinishedStubbingException`, you would get `WrongTypeOfReturnValue` since you tell mockito to return a string ("deep") from `Foo.getBar()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems Mockito gets confused when you call your deep stub in then `when` method. I was able to work around it by calling `mock.getBar()` separately:

```
    Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Bar bar = mock.getBar();
    doReturn("deep").when(bar).getName();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I don't know why all examples when searching around is  `when(mock.getBar()).getName()`

Comment: Only (minor) downside of this is that `verify` will see `mock.getBar()` called in the second line of the code block already. To be clear, this is not critique of the answer, more of a heads up :-)

Comment: This separation works because the `mock.getBar()` is invoked before calling `doReturn(...)`. The `when(...)` approach works because for `when(...)` to be called, its passing argument needs to be resolved first, which is the returned reference of the `mock.getBar()` call. That is because for `doReurn` and `when` to work, the passed mock has to be registered first, which happens during the `mock.getBar()` stubbing.